# SQL Server XML with dynamic arguments

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing, sqlxml

I have the following table called 'mdx'

```
yearnumber  yearstart   yearend weeknumber  quantity
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    1   1826
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    2   1225
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    3   452
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    4   276
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    5   673
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    6   1986
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    7   3806
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    8   3608
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    9   3841
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    10  3356
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    11  3436
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    12  3437
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    13  3611
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    14  3354
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    15  3743
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    16  3508
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    17  3440
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    18  3467
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    19  2816
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    20  2998
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    21  2796
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    22  2624
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    23  2458
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    24  1924
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    25  1816
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    26  1671
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    27  1111
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    28  1036
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    29  746
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    30  590
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    31  665
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    32  393
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    33  442
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    34  2042
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    35  387
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    36  24
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    37  30
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    38  44
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    39  113
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    40  23
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    41  18
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    42  1624
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    43  3760
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    44  3645
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    45  3964
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    46  3807
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    47  4048
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    48  3862
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    49  3677
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    50  3695
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    51  3871
1   11-22-15    11-19-16    52  3686
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    1   3694
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    2   4240
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    3   4287
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    4   4751
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    5   5536
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    6   3712
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    7   3367
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    8   3598
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    9   3461
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    10  3334
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    11  3325
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    12  3313
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    13  3417
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    14  3396
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    15  3326
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    16  3274
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    17  3473
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    18  3442
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    19  3293
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    20  3114
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    21  3116
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    22  3664
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    23  3165
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    24  2896
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    25  3113
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    26  3183
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    27  2912
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    28  3043
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    29  3046
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    30  3033
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    31  3212
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    32  3294
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    33  3210
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    34  3303
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    35  3229
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    36  3313
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    37  3338
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    38  3432
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    39  3340
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    40  3597
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    41  3628
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    42  3412
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    43  3332
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    44  3313
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    45  3637
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    46  3498
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    47  3230
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    48  2591
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    49  2937
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    50  2964
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    51  2740
2   11-23-14    11-21-15    52  1982
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    1   4607
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    2   5018
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    3   5054
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    4   5834
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    5   5944
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    6   3992
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    7   4298
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    8   4307
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    9   4187
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    10  4269
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    11  4012
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    12  4392
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    13  4536
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    14  4173
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    15  4053
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    16  3882
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    17  4053
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    18  3990
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    19  3992
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    20  3489
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    21  3797
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    22  3355
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    23  3438
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    24  3275
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    25  3403
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    26  3345
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    27  3282
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    28  3378
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    29  3286
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    30  3304
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    31  3179
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    32  3248
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    33  3469
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    34  3497
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    35  3360
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    36  3217
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    37  3170
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    38  3462
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    39  3528
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    40  3466
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    41  3546
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    42  3549
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    43  3350
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    44  3286
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    45  3598
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    46  3725
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    47  3573
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    48  3681
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    49  3378
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    50  3481
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    51  3477
3   11-24-13    11-22-14    52  3673
```

I'm trying to generate xml in sql server that will loo like this

```
<years>
<year yearnumber="1" yearstart="11-22-15" yearend="11-19-16">
<week weeknumber="1" quantity="10127" />
<week weeknumber="10" quantity="10959" />
<week weeknumber="11" quantity="10773" />
<week weeknumber="12" quantity="11142" />
<week weeknumber="13" quantity="11564" />
<week weeknumber="14" quantity="10923" />
<week weeknumber="15" quantity="11122" />
<week weeknumber="16" quantity="10664" />
<week weeknumber="17" quantity="10966" />
<week weeknumber="18" quantity="10899" />
<week weeknumber="19" quantity="10101" />
<week weeknumber="2" quantity="10483" />
<week weeknumber="20" quantity="9601" />
<week weeknumber="21" quantity="9709" />
<week weeknumber="22" quantity="9643" />
<week weeknumber="23" quantity="9061" />
<week weeknumber="24" quantity="8095" />
<week weeknumber="25" quantity="8332" />
<week weeknumber="26" quantity="8199" />
<week weeknumber="27" quantity="7305" />
<week weeknumber="28" quantity="7457" />
<week weeknumber="29" quantity="7078" />
<week weeknumber="3" quantity="9793" />
<week weeknumber="30" quantity="6927" />
<week weeknumber="31" quantity="7056" />
<week weeknumber="32" quantity="6935" />
<week weeknumber="33" quantity="7121" />
<week weeknumber="34" quantity="8842" />
<week weeknumber="35" quantity="6976" />
<week weeknumber="36" quantity="6554" />
<week weeknumber="37" quantity="6538" />
<week weeknumber="38" quantity="6938" />
<week weeknumber="39" quantity="6981" />
<week weeknumber="4" quantity="10861" />
<week weeknumber="40" quantity="7086" />
<week weeknumber="41" quantity="7192" />
<week weeknumber="42" quantity="8585" />
<week weeknumber="43" quantity="10442" />
<week weeknumber="44" quantity="10244" />
<week weeknumber="45" quantity="11199" />
<week weeknumber="46" quantity="11030" />
<week weeknumber="47" quantity="10851" />
<week weeknumber="48" quantity="10134" />
<week weeknumber="49" quantity="9992" />
<week weeknumber="5" quantity="12153" />
<week weeknumber="50" quantity="10140" />
<week weeknumber="51" quantity="10088" />
<week weeknumber="52" quantity="9341" />
<week weeknumber="6" quantity="9690" />
<week weeknumber="7" quantity="11471" />
<week weeknumber="8" quantity="11513" />
<week weeknumber="9" quantity="11489" />
</year>
<year yearnumber="2" yearstart="11-23-14" yearend="11-21-15">
<week weeknumber="1" quantity="10127" />
<week weeknumber="10" quantity="10959" />
<week weeknumber="11" quantity="10773" />
<week weeknumber="12" quantity="11142" />
<week weeknumber="13" quantity="11564" />
<week weeknumber="14" quantity="10923" />
<week weeknumber="15" quantity="11122" />
<week weeknumber="16" quantity="10664" />
<week weeknumber="17" quantity="10966" />
<week weeknumber="18" quantity="10899" />
<week weeknumber="19" quantity="10101" />
<week weeknumber="2" quantity="10483" />
<week weeknumber="20" quantity="9601" />
<week weeknumber="21" quantity="9709" />
<week weeknumber="22" quantity="9643" />
<week weeknumber="23" quantity="9061" />
<week weeknumber="24" quantity="8095" />
<week weeknumber="25" quantity="8332" />
<week weeknumber="26" quantity="8199" />
<week weeknumber="27" quantity="7305" />
<week weeknumber="28" quantity="7457" />
<week weeknumber="29" quantity="7078" />
<week weeknumber="3" quantity="9793" />
<week weeknumber="30" quantity="6927" />
<week weeknumber="31" quantity="7056" />
<week weeknumber="32" quantity="6935" />
<week weeknumber="33" quantity="7121" />
<week weeknumber="34" quantity="8842" />
<week weeknumber="35" quantity="6976" />
<week weeknumber="36" quantity="6554" />
<week weeknumber="37" quantity="6538" />
<week weeknumber="38" quantity="6938" />
<week weeknumber="39" quantity="6981" />
<week weeknumber="4" quantity="10861" />
<week weeknumber="40" quantity="7086" />
<week weeknumber="41" quantity="7192" />
<week weeknumber="42" quantity="8585" />
<week weeknumber="43" quantity="10442" />
<week weeknumber="44" quantity="10244" />
<week weeknumber="45" quantity="11199" />
<week weeknumber="46" quantity="11030" />
<week weeknumber="47" quantity="10851" />
<week weeknumber="48" quantity="10134" />
<week weeknumber="49" quantity="9992" />
<week weeknumber="5" quantity="12153" />
<week weeknumber="50" quantity="10140" />
<week weeknumber="51" quantity="10088" />
<week weeknumber="52" quantity="9341" />
<week weeknumber="6" quantity="9690" />
<week weeknumber="7" quantity="11471" />
<week weeknumber="8" quantity="11513" />
<week weeknumber="9" quantity="11489" />
</year>
<year yearnumber="3" yearstart="11-24-13" yearend="11-22-14">
<week weeknumber="1" quantity="10127" />
<week weeknumber="10" quantity="10959" />
<week weeknumber="11" quantity="10773" />
<week weeknumber="12" quantity="11142" />
<week weeknumber="13" quantity="11564" />
<week weeknumber="14" quantity="10923" />
<week weeknumber="15" quantity="11122" />
<week weeknumber="16" quantity="10664" />
<week weeknumber="17" quantity="10966" />
<week weeknumber="18" quantity="10899" />
<week weeknumber="19" quantity="10101" />
<week weeknumber="2" quantity="10483" />
<week weeknumber="20" quantity="9601" />
<week weeknumber="21" quantity="9709" />
<week weeknumber="22" quantity="9643" />
<week weeknumber="23" quantity="9061" />
<week weeknumber="24" quantity="8095" />
<week weeknumber="25" quantity="8332" />
<week weeknumber="26" quantity="8199" />
<week weeknumber="27" quantity="7305" />
<week weeknumber="28" quantity="7457" />
<week weeknumber="29" quantity="7078" />
<week weeknumber="3" quantity="9793" />
<week weeknumber="30" quantity="6927" />
<week weeknumber="31" quantity="7056" />
<week weeknumber="32" quantity="6935" />
<week weeknumber="33" quantity="7121" />
<week weeknumber="34" quantity="8842" />
<week weeknumber="35" quantity="6976" />
<week weeknumber="36" quantity="6554" />
<week weeknumber="37" quantity="6538" />
<week weeknumber="38" quantity="6938" />
<week weeknumber="39" quantity="6981" />
<week weeknumber="4" quantity="10861" />
<week weeknumber="40" quantity="7086" />
<week weeknumber="41" quantity="7192" />
<week weeknumber="42" quantity="8585" />
<week weeknumber="43" quantity="10442" />
<week weeknumber="44" quantity="10244" />
<week weeknumber="45" quantity="11199" />
<week weeknumber="46" quantity="11030" />
<week weeknumber="47" quantity="10851" />
<week weeknumber="48" quantity="10134" />
<week weeknumber="49" quantity="9992" />
<week weeknumber="5" quantity="12153" />
<week weeknumber="50" quantity="10140" />
<week weeknumber="51" quantity="10088" />
<week weeknumber="52" quantity="9341" />
<week weeknumber="6" quantity="9690" />
<week weeknumber="7" quantity="11471" />
<week weeknumber="8" quantity="11513" />
<week weeknumber="9" quantity="11489" />
</year>
</years>
```

As you can see the quantity sum is the same for all the years, which shouldn't be the case, it should be unique for each year, how do i format it appropriately.

OP's code (taken from comment):

```
select (CAST(yearnumber as int)) as '@yearnumber'
      , min(convert(varchar(10)
      , cast(yearstart as date), 10)) as '@yearstart'
      , max(convert(varchar(10)
      , cast(yearend as date), 10)) as '@yearend'
      , ( select cast(weeknumber as int) as '@weeknumber'
               , SUM(isnull(cast(quantity as int),0)) as '@quantity' 
          FROM [meiForecasting].[dbo].george_mdx 
          group by weeknumber 
          FOR XML PATH('week'), TYPE
        ) 
from [meiForecasting].[dbo].george_mdx 
group by yearnumber for xml path('year'), root('years')
```

Comment: I'll need help with formatting of the table above --- can't seem to find a way to edit it after posting

Comment: This is my code   
select

(CAST(yearnumber as int))   as '@yearnumber',

min(convert(varchar(10), cast(yearstart as date), 10)) as '@yearstart', 

max(convert(varchar(10), cast(yearend as date), 10)) as '@yearend',

( 

select 

cast(weeknumber as int) as '@weeknumber',

SUM(isnull(cast(quantity as int),0)) as '@quantity'

FROM [meiForecasting].[dbo].george_mdx  group by weeknumber 


FOR XML PATH('week'), TYPE)

from [meiForecasting].[dbo].george_mdx group by yearnumber

for xml path('year'), root('years')

Comment: Hi, I edited the code form the comment into your question. Please delete the comment. And for the next question, please add a **reduced** sample table, better as *ready-to-copy* `INSERT` statement, best as full **MCVE**. This makes it easier for helpers to set up a test scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show us how you are generating this XML, but - quite sure - you are doing this in some kind of string concatenation, or you have your dates as string values. Both is quite bad...

There is one **big weakness** in your XML: `yearstart="11-24-13"`

You should **always avoid culture specific date/time formats**. Even worse is culture specific with a two digit year. The worst are formats with **language** specific parts like `1 Dec 2016`. Imagine a date like `02-03-04`. Depending on the reading system you'd get numerous different values from this.

The **proper format within XML is ISO8601**. Using `FOR XML` will do this for you implicitly.

Check this. If it works, you just have to replace the `@tbl` with your actual table's name:

First I create a *mock-up* test scenario (you don't need this later)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YearNumber INT,YearStart DATE,YearEnd DATE,WeekNumber INT,Quantity INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),1,1826)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),2,1225)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),3,452)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),4,276)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),5,673)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),6,1986)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),7,3806)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),8,3608)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),9,3841)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),10,3356)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),11,3436)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),12,3437)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),13,3611)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),14,3354)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),15,3743)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),16,3508)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),17,3440)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),18,3467)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),19,2816)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),20,2998)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),21,2796)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),22,2624)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),23,2458)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),24,1924)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),25,1816)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),26,1671)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),27,1111)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),28,1036)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),29,746)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),30,590)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),31,665)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),32,393)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),33,442)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),34,2042)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),35,387)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),36,24)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),37,30)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),38,44)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),39,113)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),40,23)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),41,18)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),42,1624)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),43,3760)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),44,3645)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),45,3964)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),46,3807)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),47,4048)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),48,3862)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),49,3677)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),50,3695)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),51,3871)
,(1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-15',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-19-16',1),52,3686)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),1,3694)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),2,4240)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),3,4287)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),4,4751)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),5,5536)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),6,3712)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),7,3367)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),8,3598)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),9,3461)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),10,3334)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),11,3325)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),12,3313)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),13,3417)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),14,3396)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),15,3326)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),16,3274)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),17,3473)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),18,3442)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),19,3293)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),20,3114)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),21,3116)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),22,3664)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),23,3165)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),24,2896)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),25,3113)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),26,3183)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),27,2912)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),28,3043)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),29,3046)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),30,3033)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),31,3212)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),32,3294)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),33,3210)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),34,3303)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),35,3229)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),36,3313)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),37,3338)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),38,3432)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),39,3340)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),40,3597)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),41,3628)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),42,3412)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),43,3332)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),44,3313)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),45,3637)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),46,3498)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),47,3230)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),48,2591)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),49,2937)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),50,2964)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),51,2740)
,(2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-23-14',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-21-15',1),52,1982)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),1,4607)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),2,5018)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),3,5054)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),4,5834)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),5,5944)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),6,3992)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),7,4298)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),8,4307)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),9,4187)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),10,4269)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),11,4012)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),12,4392)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),13,4536)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),14,4173)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),15,4053)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),16,3882)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),17,4053)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),18,3990)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),19,3992)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),20,3489)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),21,3797)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),22,3355)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),23,3438)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),24,3275)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),25,3403)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),26,3345)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),27,3282)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),28,3378)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),29,3286)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),30,3304)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),31,3179)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),32,3248)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),33,3469)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),34,3497)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),35,3360)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),36,3217)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),37,3170)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),38,3462)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),39,3528)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),40,3466)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),41,3546)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),42,3549)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),43,3350)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),44,3286)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),45,3598)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),46,3725)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),47,3573)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),48,3681)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),49,3378)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),50,3481)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),51,3477)
,(3,CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-24-13',1),CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-22-14',1),52,3673);
```

--This is the actual query:

```
SELECT YearNumber AS [@yearnumber]
      ,YearStart AS [@yearstart]
      ,YearEnd AS [@yearend]
      ,(
        SELECT x.WeekNumber AS [@weeknumber]
              ,x.Quantity AS [@quantity]    
        FROM @tbl AS X
        WHERE X.YearNumber=tbl.YearNumber
        FOR XML PATH('week'),TYPE 
       )
FROM @tbl AS tbl
GROUP BY YearNumber,YearStart,YearEnd
FOR XML PATH('year'),ROOT('years')
```

And this is the result

```
<years>
  <year yearnumber="1" yearstart="2015-11-22" yearend="2016-11-19">
    <week weeknumber="1" quantity="1826" />
    <week weeknumber="2" quantity="1225" />
    <week weeknumber="3" quantity="452" />
    <week weeknumber="4" quantity="276" />
    <week weeknumber="5" quantity="673" />
    <week weeknumber="6" quantity="1986" />
    <week weeknumber="7" quantity="3806" />
    <week weeknumber="8" quantity="3608" />
    <week weeknumber="9" quantity="3841" />
    <week weeknumber="10" quantity="3356" />
    <week weeknumber="11" quantity="3436" />
    <week weeknumber="12" quantity="3437" />
    <week weeknumber="13" quantity="3611" />
    <week weeknumber="14" quantity="3354" />
    <week weeknumber="15" quantity="3743" />
    <week weeknumber="16" quantity="3508" />
    <week weeknumber="17" quantity="3440" />
    <week weeknumber="18" quantity="3467" />
    <week weeknumber="19" quantity="2816" />
    <week weeknumber="20" quantity="2998" />
    <week weeknumber="21" quantity="2796" />
    <week weeknumber="22" quantity="2624" />
    <week weeknumber="23" quantity="2458" />
    <week weeknumber="24" quantity="1924" />
    <week weeknumber="25" quantity="1816" />
    <week weeknumber="26" quantity="1671" />
    <week weeknumber="27" quantity="1111" />
    <week weeknumber="28" quantity="1036" />
    <week weeknumber="29" quantity="746" />
    <week weeknumber="30" quantity="590" />
    <week weeknumber="31" quantity="665" />
    <week weeknumber="32" quantity="393" />
    <week weeknumber="33" quantity="442" />
    <week weeknumber="34" quantity="2042" />
    <week weeknumber="35" quantity="387" />
    <week weeknumber="36" quantity="24" />
    <week weeknumber="37" quantity="30" />
    <week weeknumber="38" quantity="44" />
    <week weeknumber="39" quantity="113" />
    <week weeknumber="40" quantity="23" />
    <week weeknumber="41" quantity="18" />
    <week weeknumber="42" quantity="1624" />
    <week weeknumber="43" quantity="3760" />
    <week weeknumber="44" quantity="3645" />
    <week weeknumber="45" quantity="3964" />
    <week weeknumber="46" quantity="3807" />
    <week weeknumber="47" quantity="4048" />
    <week weeknumber="48" quantity="3862" />
    <week weeknumber="49" quantity="3677" />
    <week weeknumber="50" quantity="3695" />
    <week weeknumber="51" quantity="3871" />
    <week weeknumber="52" quantity="3686" />
  </year>
  <year yearnumber="2" yearstart="2014-11-23" yearend="2015-11-21">
    <week weeknumber="1" quantity="3694" />
    <week weeknumber="2" quantity="4240" />
    <week weeknumber="3" quantity="4287" />
    <week weeknumber="4" quantity="4751" />
    <week weeknumber="5" quantity="5536" />
    <week weeknumber="6" quantity="3712" />
    <week weeknumber="7" quantity="3367" />
    <week weeknumber="8" quantity="3598" />
    <week weeknumber="9" quantity="3461" />
    <week weeknumber="10" quantity="3334" />
    <week weeknumber="11" quantity="3325" />
    <week weeknumber="12" quantity="3313" />
    <week weeknumber="13" quantity="3417" />
    <week weeknumber="14" quantity="3396" />
    <week weeknumber="15" quantity="3326" />
    <week weeknumber="16" quantity="3274" />
    <week weeknumber="17" quantity="3473" />
    <week weeknumber="18" quantity="3442" />
    <week weeknumber="19" quantity="3293" />
    <week weeknumber="20" quantity="3114" />
    <week weeknumber="21" quantity="3116" />
    <week weeknumber="22" quantity="3664" />
    <week weeknumber="23" quantity="3165" />
    <week weeknumber="24" quantity="2896" />
    <week weeknumber="25" quantity="3113" />
    <week weeknumber="26" quantity="3183" />
    <week weeknumber="27" quantity="2912" />
    <week weeknumber="28" quantity="3043" />
    <week weeknumber="29" quantity="3046" />
    <week weeknumber="30" quantity="3033" />
    <week weeknumber="31" quantity="3212" />
    <week weeknumber="32" quantity="3294" />
    <week weeknumber="33" quantity="3210" />
    <week weeknumber="34" quantity="3303" />
    <week weeknumber="35" quantity="3229" />
    <week weeknumber="36" quantity="3313" />
    <week weeknumber="37" quantity="3338" />
    <week weeknumber="38" quantity="3432" />
    <week weeknumber="39" quantity="3340" />
    <week weeknumber="40" quantity="3597" />
    <week weeknumber="41" quantity="3628" />
    <week weeknumber="42" quantity="3412" />
    <week weeknumber="43" quantity="3332" />
    <week weeknumber="44" quantity="3313" />
    <week weeknumber="45" quantity="3637" />
    <week weeknumber="46" quantity="3498" />
    <week weeknumber="47" quantity="3230" />
    <week weeknumber="48" quantity="2591" />
    <week weeknumber="49" quantity="2937" />
    <week weeknumber="50" quantity="2964" />
    <week weeknumber="51" quantity="2740" />
    <week weeknumber="52" quantity="1982" />
  </year>
  <year yearnumber="3" yearstart="2013-11-24" yearend="2014-11-22">
    <week weeknumber="1" quantity="4607" />
    <week weeknumber="2" quantity="5018" />
    <week weeknumber="3" quantity="5054" />
    <week weeknumber="4" quantity="5834" />
    <week weeknumber="5" quantity="5944" />
    <week weeknumber="6" quantity="3992" />
    <week weeknumber="7" quantity="4298" />
    <week weeknumber="8" quantity="4307" />
    <week weeknumber="9" quantity="4187" />
    <week weeknumber="10" quantity="4269" />
    <week weeknumber="11" quantity="4012" />
    <week weeknumber="12" quantity="4392" />
    <week weeknumber="13" quantity="4536" />
    <week weeknumber="14" quantity="4173" />
    <week weeknumber="15" quantity="4053" />
    <week weeknumber="16" quantity="3882" />
    <week weeknumber="17" quantity="4053" />
    <week weeknumber="18" quantity="3990" />
    <week weeknumber="19" quantity="3992" />
    <week weeknumber="20" quantity="3489" />
    <week weeknumber="21" quantity="3797" />
    <week weeknumber="22" quantity="3355" />
    <week weeknumber="23" quantity="3438" />
    <week weeknumber="24" quantity="3275" />
    <week weeknumber="25" quantity="3403" />
    <week weeknumber="26" quantity="3345" />
    <week weeknumber="27" quantity="3282" />
    <week weeknumber="28" quantity="3378" />
    <week weeknumber="29" quantity="3286" />
    <week weeknumber="30" quantity="3304" />
    <week weeknumber="31" quantity="3179" />
    <week weeknumber="32" quantity="3248" />
    <week weeknumber="33" quantity="3469" />
    <week weeknumber="34" quantity="3497" />
    <week weeknumber="35" quantity="3360" />
    <week weeknumber="36" quantity="3217" />
    <week weeknumber="37" quantity="3170" />
    <week weeknumber="38" quantity="3462" />
    <week weeknumber="39" quantity="3528" />
    <week weeknumber="40" quantity="3466" />
    <week weeknumber="41" quantity="3546" />
    <week weeknumber="42" quantity="3549" />
    <week weeknumber="43" quantity="3350" />
    <week weeknumber="44" quantity="3286" />
    <week weeknumber="45" quantity="3598" />
    <week weeknumber="46" quantity="3725" />
    <week weeknumber="47" quantity="3573" />
    <week weeknumber="48" quantity="3681" />
    <week weeknumber="49" quantity="3378" />
    <week weeknumber="50" quantity="3481" />
    <week weeknumber="51" quantity="3477" />
    <week weeknumber="52" quantity="3673" />
  </year>
</years>
```