# Multiple Root XML - SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, xmla

I have the following XML code and I'm trying to generate the xml shown after the code - tried several approaches but no success.

There are 2 tables: `[meiForecasting].[dbo].george_mdx` has the data shown below and the data for the other follows. I'm trying to join the tables so I can get the xml such that for each `UnitPrice` in `george_mdx` that falls between each group of `priceband` (`pricedfrom` - `pricedto`), I'll be able to generate the xml format that follows.

See my code below.

The inner xml works perfectly, but the outer elements (`priceband` and `pricebands`) are the problem.

```
(Select

(select

pb.pricebandID '@Id',
pb.[pricedfrom] '@start',
pb.[PricedTo] '@end',

(
SELECT  cast(yearnumber as int)  AS '@number'
,(convert(varchar(12), cast(yearstart as date), 126)) AS '@yearstart'
  ,(convert(varchar(12), cast(yearend as date), 126)) AS '@yearend'
  ,(
    SELECT  cast(X.WeekNumber as int) AS '@number'
          ,cast(x.Quantity as int) AS '@units'    
    FROM  [meiForecasting].[dbo].george_mdx AS X
    WHERE cast(X.YearNumber as int)=cast(tbl.YearNumber as int)
    FOR XML PATH('week'),TYPE 
   )
FROM  [meiForecasting].[dbo].george_mdx AS tbl inner join         meiforecasting.PLANNING.PriceBand as pb 
ON (tbl.unitprice <= pb.PricedTo AND tbl.unitprice >= pb.PricedFrom)
GROUP BY YearNumber,YearStart,YearEnd, pb.GroupID
FOR XML PATH('year'),ROOT('years') 
    )
)

FOR XML PATH ('Priceband'),ROOT ('PriceBands')
)
)
```

table [meiForecasting].[dbo].george_mdx

```
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| yearnumber | weeknumber | quantity | unitprice |
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
|          1 |         44 |     3807 |  45662.55 |
|          1 |         45 |     4048 |  45295.00 |
|          1 |         46 |     3862 |  45047.68 |
|          1 |         47 |     3677 |  41013.00 |
|          1 |         48 |     3695 |  39387.43 |
|          1 |         49 |     3871 |  43199.02 |
|          1 |         50 |     3686 |  39131.82 |
|          2 |          1 |     4287 |  51086.02 |
|          2 |          2 |     4751 |  60404.40 |
|          2 |          3 |     5536 |  67468.90 |
|          2 |          4 |     3712 |  45776.32 |
|          2 |          5 |     3367 |  44288.19 |
|          2 |          6 |     3598 |  45307.49 |
|          2 |          7 |     3461 |  47757.59 |
|          2 |          8 |     3334 |  43771.33 |
|          2 |          9 |     3325 |  41656.88 |
|          2 |         10 |     3313 |  44738.39 |
|          2 |         32 |     3303 |  40144.35 |
|          2 |         33 |     3229 |  45892.27 |
|          2 |         34 |     3313 |  44570.07 |
|          2 |         35 |     3338 |  44978.12 |
|          2 |         36 |     3432 |  46760.30 |
|          2 |         37 |     3340 |  48341.05 |
|          2 |         38 |     3597 |  48673.97 |
|          2 |         39 |     3628 |  48636.17 |
|          3 |         29 |     3179 |  43610.97 |
+------------+------------+----------+-----------+


+--------------------+---------+----------+
|    Planning.       |priceband|          |
+--------------------+---------+----------+
|                    |
| 43                 |    0.00 |  1000.00 |
| 45                 |    0.00 |  1000.00 |
| 49                 |    0.00 |   999.99 |
| 50                 | 1000.00 |  1999.99 |
| 51                 | 2000.00 |  9999.00 |
| 52                 |    0.00 |    15.00 |
| 53                 |   15.01 |   300.00 |
| 62                 |    0.00 |    15.00 |
| 63                 |   15.01 |   200.00 |
| 69                 |  100.00 |   500.99 |
| 70                 |  501.00 |  1000.00 |
| 78                 |    0.00 |   299.99 |
| 79                 |  300.00 |   399.99 |
| 80                 |  400.00 |   499.99 |
| 81                 |  500.00 |   599.99 |
| 82                 |  600.00 |   699.99 |
| 83                 |  700.00 |   999.99 |
| 84                 | 1000.00 | 10000.00 |
| 125                |   50.00 |    99.99 |
| 126                |  100.00 |   199.99 |
| 127                |  200.00 |   299.99 |
| 128                |  300.00 |   399.99 |
| 129                |  400.00 |  9999.00 |
+--------------------+---------+----------+
```

expected XML (SAMPLE ONLY-Figures may not be correct)

```
<priceBands> <priceBand id="1" end="99.99" start="0.00"> 
<years> <year number="1"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> -<year number="2"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> <year number="3"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> -<year number="4"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> <year number="5"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>
</year> </years> </priceBand> 

<priceBand id="2" end="499.99" start="100.00">

 <years> <year number="1"> 
 <week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> <year number="2"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> <year number="3"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> <year number="4"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> -<year number="5"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
.
.
.
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> </years> </priceBand> 

<priceBand id="3" end="999.99" start="500.00"> <years> <year number="1"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> <year number="2"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> <year number="3"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> -<year number="4"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>

</year> <year number="5"> 
<week number="1" units="41"/>
<week number="2" units="41"/>
<week number="3" units="41"/>
<week number="4" units="41"/>
<week number="5" units="41"/>
<week number="6" units="41"/>
<week number="7" units="41"/>
<week number="8" units="41"/>
<week number="9" units="41"/>
<week number="10" units="41"/>
<week number="11" units="41"/>
<week number="12" units="41"/>
<week number="13" units="41"/>
<week number="14" units="41"/>
<week number="15" units="41"/>
<week number="16" units="41"/>
<week number="17" units="41"/>
<week number="18" units="41"/>
<week number="19" units="41"/>
<week number="20" units="41"/>
<week number="21" units="41"/>
<week number="22" units="41"/>
<week number="23" units="41"/>
<week number="24" units="41"/>
<week number="25" units="41"/>
<week number="26" units="41"/>
<week number="27" units="41"/>
<week number="28" units="41"/>
<week number="29" units="41"/>
<week number="30" units="41"/>
<week number="31" units="41"/>
<week number="32" units="41"/>
<week number="33" units="41"/>
<week number="34" units="41"/>
<week number="35" units="41"/>
<week number="36" units="41"/>
<week number="37" units="41"/>
<week number="38" units="41"/>
<week number="39" units="41"/>
<week number="40" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="42" units="41"/>
<week number="43" units="41"/>
<week number="44" units="41"/>
<week number="45" units="41"/>
<week number="46" units="41"/>
<week number="47" units="41"/>
<week number="48" units="41"/>
<week number="49" units="41"/>
<week number="50" units="41"/>
<week number="41" units="41"/>
<week number="52" units="41"/>
</year> </years> 
</priceBand> </priceBands>
```

Comment: As I've told you in [your related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40923206/5089204). It would be really nice to include **reduced sample data**. Just some rows per group to understand the logic. On the other hand it is crucial to add your **expected output with corresponding figures**. Just try to think with a foreigner's head. I have no idea, what you are doing... Best is a [MCVE (Details here)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Further more: Your query does not fit to the tables given. There is no `yearstart` or `yearend` in your sample tables... Providing an **MCVE** would help you to KISS (*keep it small and simple*) and it would help to avoid such annoying errors...

Comment: One more hint: Look at your previous question. I did your work there for you... See how the table variables are declared and filled? This is exactly what you should do here (with **reduced!!** data)

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo, I know you are a genius, I'll take your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My magic glass bulb tells me, that you might be looking for something like this:

But (see my comments below your question) there's a lot not clear...

```
SELECT pricebandID AS [@id]
      ,pricedTo AS [@end]
      ,pricedFrom AS [@start]
      ,(
        SELECT  cast(yearnumber as int)  AS '@number'
        ,(convert(varchar(12), cast(yearstart as date), 126)) AS '@yearstart'
          ,(convert(varchar(12), cast(yearend as date), 126)) AS '@yearend'
          ,(
            SELECT  cast(X.WeekNumber as int) AS '@number'
                  ,cast(x.Quantity as int) AS '@units'    
            FROM  @george_mdx AS X
            WHERE cast(X.YearNumber as int)=cast(tbl.YearNumber as int)
              AND X.unitprice BETWEEN pl.pricedFrom AND pl.pricedTo
            FOR XML PATH('week'),TYPE 
           )
        FROM  @george_mdx AS tbl 
        WHERE tbl.unitprice BETWEEN pl.pricedFrom AND pl.pricedTo
        GROUP BY YearNumber,YearStart,YearEnd
        FOR XML PATH('year'),ROOT('years') 
        )

FROM @Planning AS pl
FOR XML PATH('priceBand'),ROOT('priceBands')
```

Comment: Thanks Shnugo -- that worked with a few modifications